# Cant horizontally scroll to access content in chrome

Tags: html, css, google-chrome, extjs

I have a grid made with extjs, which is essentially, as you may have guessed, a complex HTML table. In google chrome I notice that all the way to the right, the final column is 'cut off' by the browser, and I cannot horizontally scroll to reach it. Using the chrome developer tools I have verified that the column exists, and I can adjust it to be larger, but still cannot scroll to see it.

Any ideas what CSS properties could be causing this? The table is also wrapped inside a `div`.

Comment: What is your current CSS? My guess would be `overflow` but that's just a shot in the dark.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
overflow-x: hidden;
```

Will hide horizontal scrolling if your tables extends past the div

```
overflow: hidden;
```

Will hide both overflow-x and overflow-y

Can you provide a link?

Comment: its a website internal to my company, I would provide a code sample but its much too large

Comment: also, the horizontal scroll bar Im referring to is that of my browser, not a scroll bar attached to the table

Comment: I would check for overflow, or max-width, on a parent element. It is possible your website has a max-width on a parent container or perhaps the body it self has overflow-x hidden.

Comment: is that something that would affect chrome only and not firefox?

Comment: I have never ran into a cross browser issue to my knowledge.

Comment: I did a replace all of the overflow: hidden in my css file for this 3rd party grid, it made the display very ugly but i was able to determine that at least 1 of the 121 'overflow: hidden' properties was the culprit. thanks!

Answer (score 0):

When you develop a grid with extJS, there won't be problem in css unless you explicitly modify it. Check your scroll property of grid. try scroll:true instead of horizontal or vertical with your extJS grid.